# How can I search all of my computers from one computer?

Tags: networking, search, windows-search

Is there any way to search through the files of multiple computers from one computer? I want to find a way to search all of my files, which are on three different computers, from one computer. I have Linux Mint running on two of them, and Windows running on one of them.

Comment: @Karan Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: @Karan I clarified the wording of the original question. That should clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If Linux has Samba installed and Windows has file sharing enabled, you could mount the other computers' drives as network drives in Windows and then search "My Computer", which should include the network drives. I do not know the process to do this on Linux, but the concept is the same. Sorry of the half-answer.

Comment: How can you enable file sharing on Windows, then?

Comment: It depends on the version. If you are in Windows 7 (what I'm on now), click the network icon in the system tray/notification area and then "Open Network and Sharing Center", look for something saying "Home Network" or "Work Network". Either of these mean sharing should be enabled already. If not, or you're on another version, post back. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Just mount the hidden drive `c$` (exchange `c` with your drive letter), however you'll need to authenticate yourself with your Windows credentials. This should give you access to the entire Windows partition based on the users permissions.

Comment: Would this make it possible to search multiple hard disks (instead of just one hard disk)?

Comment: If you mount them to different locations, yes.